# Save photo to iphone camera roll with a custom name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera

I am trying to save a photo taken from my app to camera roll, this can be done by using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum, however, I noticed there isn't any way to set the photo name by using this approach, am I right?

I also tried to save a image file with a name by using UIImageJPEGRepresentation, however, I can only save it to my app's document folder but not camera roll.

Is there any way to save photo to camera roll with a custom name?

Thanks advance for your kindly help.

John

Answer (score 4):

no, no way to save with a custom name to the camera roll.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to kinda do that, by setting the image metadata:
if you set the IPTC metadata field "Object Name", this will be shown as the image title in iPhoto.

See details (and code) at http://ootips.org/yonat/how-to-set-the-image-name-when-saving-to-the-camera-roll/ .

Comment: Not able to define `kCGImagePropertyIPTCDictionary`

Comment: @jeevanRao You need to add `#import <ImageIO/CGImageProperties.h>` and of course also `#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>`.

Comment: Well, I included all those headers. You can also see in my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799248/meta-data-dictionary-of-uiimage-does-not-got-value-for-iptc-key

Comment: Only difference between http://ootips.org/yonat/how-to-set-the-image-name-when-saving-to-the-camera-roll/ and in my code is, i did not used UIImagePickerController, instead I used image (screenshot) taken from document directory.

Comment: So it seems that these metadata are not save by the iPhone. If you want, you can add them.

Comment: Ok Thanks :-) How can I add them, please help me with example :-)

Comment: Just add them to the metadata dictionary. If you're having trouble with that, use the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003648).